# Which PPA to use for installing the latest stable version of VLC on Kubuntu 17.04?

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, ppa, vlc, 17.04

Please, what is the recommended PPA to use for installing the latest stable version of the VLC player on **Kubuntu 17.04**?

Of course, before posting this question, I did a good research but couldn't decide on the right PPA. I found though the following related PPAs:

- https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily
- https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily
- https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/ubuntu/vlc

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first two are the official PPA's , First one is the Stable, when it comes to PPA's you want to stay as close to Official as possible

Comment: +1 - Thank you for your comment. I will add the first PPA then based on your recommendation.

Comment: if it proves stable enough, you can answer your own question and accept the answer to close the Question as answered

Comment: The 1st. & last ppa's you mentioned don't have builds for 17.04. (- The last one is pretty much dead anyway. So only the middle one supports 17.04. The vlc provided in 17.04 from Ubuntu repos is pretty much the latest stable version, the middle ppa is for vlc-3.x which is still being developed